# Why does my JSON doesn't get decoded in my PHP script while using decode?

Tags: php, json, decode

I'm working on rewriting a Java Programm of mine in PHP but have close to none experience with PHP so I stick together code and inform myself on the fly but I'm already stuck with decoding my file (which works fine in my Java version where I use the GSON library for decoding) and don't really have an Idea where to look for my problem
I have this very basic code:

```
public $lieder;
public function convertJSONtoARRAY($newJSONFile)
{
    $stringJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("$newJSONFile");
    $lieder = json_decode($stringJsonFileContents);
}
```

and this :

```
<?php
include ('LiederEditor.php');
include ('Index.json');
$editor = new LiederEditor();
$editor -> convertJSONtoARRAY("Index.json");
echo var_dump("$editor->lieder");
?>
```

Cleaner version for now:

```
public $lieder;
public function convertJSONtoARRAY($newJSONFile)
    {
        $stringJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("$newJSONFile");
        $this ->lieder = json_decode($stringJsonFileContents,true);
    }
```

and

```
<?php
include ('LiederEditor.php');
$editor = new LiederEditor();
$editor -> convertJSONtoARRAY("Index.json");
var_dump($editor->lieder);
?>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "number": "A01",
    "name": "Gaudeamus Igitur, Kindleben",
    "slug": "gaudeamus-igitur",
    "language": "lat",
    "category": "Traditionell",
    "year": 1781,
    "position": 10010,
    "url": "https://beta.acel.lu/group/songbook/gaudeamus-igitur",
    "update_time": 1504601629,
    "paragraphs": [
      {
        "id": 1660,
        "type": "normal",
        "content": "|: Gaudeamus igitur\niuvenes dum sumus :|\npost iucundam iuventutem,\npost molestam senectutem,\n|: nos habebit humus! :|"
      },
      {
        "id": 1661,
        "type": "normal",
        "content": "|: Ubi sunt qui ante nos\nin mundo fuere? :|\nvadite ad superos\ntransite ad inferos\n|: ubi iam fuere. :|"
      },
      {
        "id": 1662,
        "type": "normal",
        "content": "|: Vita nostra brevis est,\nbrevi finietur, :|\nvenit mors velociter,\nrapit nos atrociter\n|: nemini parcetur! :|"
      },
      {
        "id": 1663,
        "type": "normal",
        "content": "|: Vivat academia,\nvivant professores! :|\nvivat membrum quodlibet,\nvivant membra quaelibet,\n|: semper sint in flore! :|"
      },
      {
        "id": 1664,
        "type": "normal",
        "content": "|: Vivant omnes virgines\nfaciles, formosae, :|\nvivant et mulieres,\ntenerae, amabiles,\n|: bonae, laboriosae :|"
      },
      {
        "id": 1665,
        "type": "normal",
        "content": "|: Vivat et res publica,\net qui illam regit! :|\nvivat nostra civitas,\nmaecenatum caritas,\n|: quae nos hic protegit! :|"
      },
```

Comment: I closed your JSON with `]}` after removing the trailing comma and ran the whole thing through json_deocde, which worked for me. There might be an issue later in the JSON. You could var_dump the results of `file_get_contents` to verify that clean JSON is being read from the file. You should also validate the rest of the JSON using a tool like https://jsonlint.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$this` to assign a value to your class variable `$lieder`. You should also pass `true` to `json_decode` if you want it to return an associative array instead of an object. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```php
public $lieder;
public function convertJSONtoARRAY($newJSONFile)
{
    $stringJsonFileContents = file_get_contents($newJSONFile);
    $this->lieder = json_decode($stringJsonFileContents, true);
}
```

You also don't need quotes around the variable `$newJSONFile`

A couple of other things:

You don't need to `include('Index.json')` if you are reading it later via `file_get_contents`, and you shouldn't use quotes when you var_dump `$editor->lieder`. As @brombeer points out, you also don't need to `echo` the result of `var_dump`:

```php
<?php
include ('LiederEditor.php');
$editor = new LiederEditor();
$editor -> convertJSONtoARRAY("Index.json");
var_dump($editor->lieder);
```

Comment: And you don't need `echo` if you `var_dump`

Comment: Good call. Missed that. I just added it to the answer.

Comment: And since the method's purpose is to return an ARRAY, you should use `json_decode($stringJsonFileContents, true)`

Comment: Ok fix up my code with these changes but funny enough it still dumps the undecoded json string instead of the decoded array

Comment: Could you post the structure of the `Index.json` file?

Comment: The content of the file is too huge for stackoverflow but I could post the first one as exemple

Comment: Perfect. If the contents of the JSON file is surrounded by quotes, then the entire thing will be interpreted as a string. I'm wondering if that's the issue.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to edit this answer rather than your post, FYI

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it can't handle the array but there should be a possibility in php to decode more complex Json files

Comment: I see now, didn't thought I could edit other peoples post xd

Comment: To rule out a problem with the contents of your JSON file: You can either pass JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR as the third argument of json_decode() if you're on PHP 7.3+, or call json_last_error_msg() after json_decode(). Both will give you a clear description of the problem with your JSON file, if there is one. Are you sure you removed include ('Index.json'); from your code?

Comment: include ('Index.json') is removed and I got a syntax error

Comment: ok quick update just replaced the json with another version of the (what I thought) same file and now I got a huge array as a result thanks for helping out ^^